# Linq to sql - nested select with groupby

Tags: linq

I have the following SQL query:

```
 SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Bil_Audit_BillingParameter] WHERE ([Status4Eyes]!='APPROVED' OR [Status4Eyes] IS NULL )AND
        [LastComment] != '' AND
        (Service='EUR' OR Service='S1') AND
        [AudId] IN (SELECT MAX([AudId])
        FROM [Bil_Audit_BillingParameter]
        GROUP BY ID) UNION SELECT * FROM 
                                 [dbo].Bil_Audit_BillingParameter] WHERE ([Status4Eyes]!='APPROVED' OR [Status4Eyes] IS NULL) AND
                                 [LastComment] != '' AND
                                 (Service='EUR' OR Service='S1') AND
                                 [AudId] IN (SELECT MIN([AudId])
                                 FROM [Bil_Audit_BillingParameter]
                                 GROUP BY ID)
```

How it is converting to linq? I tried the following , but ends up with error.

```
public IQueryable<ParameterUpdates> Get(ODataQueryOptions op)
    {


        var audIdMax = db.ParameterUpdates.GroupBy(x => x.ID).Select(v => v.Max(x => x.AudId));
        var audIdMin = db.ParameterUpdates.GroupBy(x => x.ID).Select(a => a.Min(x => x.AudId));

        var results1 = db.ParameterUpdates.Where(p => (!p.Status4Eyes.Contains("Approved") || string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Status4Eyes)) && 
                                                !p.LastComment.Contains("NULL") &&
                                                (p.Service.Contains("EUR") || p.Service.Contains("S1")) &&
                                                p.AudId.Equals(audIdMax));

        var results2 = db.ParameterUpdates.Where(p => (!p.Status4Eyes.Contains("Approved") || string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Status4Eyes)) &&
                                                !p.LastComment.Contains("NULL") &&
                                                (p.Service.Contains("EUR") || p.Service.Contains("S1")) &&
                                                p.AudId.Equals(audIdMin));
        var results = results1.Union(results2);

        return results.AsQueryable();
    }
```

Could anyone please help.

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Please [edit] and paste code in place of images. To format text region as code click `[{ }]` button at the top of the editor.

Comment: Does that SQL even work?  Your subqueries have no WHERE clause to limit the repsonse to one ID nor even the ID in the select to know what id each max/min are for.

Comment: @JamesCurran The SQL doesn't need any of that - you are selecting the max AuditID from each group of ID's and using `IN` on that list.

Comment: @NetMage - aha.. I was playing with that code, using my own tables, and in the column I was using in place of AudId, the values weren't unique.  Nevertheless, doing a join would be better then seeking.

Comment: @sariga s Babu  can you please let me know if an answer worked for you below?

Comment: @kblau The query you provided works perfectly!! many thanks

Comment: @ISHIDA below is  the error i was getting: 
"Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported."

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, first group by id create the filter output. Then inner join the filter with max or min audit id with the actual table and find the result.

```
var filter = ParameterUpdate.Where(p => (p.status == "Approved" || p.status == null)
                                         && p.lastComment != ""
                                         &&(p.service=="EUR" || p.service=="S1")).GroupBy(p => p.id);

var result = (from p in ParameterUpdate
              from f in filter
              where p.auditId == f.Min(m => m.auditId) ||
                    p.auditId == f.Max(m => m.auditId)
              select p);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public IQueryable<ParameterUpdates> Get()
    {
        var groupMax = db.ParameterUpdates
        .GroupBy(u => u.ID)
        .Select(grp => grp.Max(x => x.AudId));

        var groupMin = db.ParameterUpdates
       .GroupBy(u => u.ID)
       .Select(grp => grp.Min(x => x.AudId));

        var results = (db.ParameterUpdates.
            Where(r => (r.Status4Eyes != "APPROVED" || r.Status4Eyes == null) &&
            (r.LastComment != null) &&
            (r.Service == "EUR" || r.Service == "S1") &&
            (groupMax.Contains(r.AudId) || groupMin.Contains(r.AudId))
            )).ToList();


        return results.AsQueryable();
```